# Issue JWT after OTP verification in ASP NET Core Web API

Tags: asp.net-core-webapi, jwt, one-time-password

I am using .NET Core 3.1 in my Web API project. In that, I have used JWT authentication. Now I want to allow users to log in or register using their mobile number. So when the user enters the mobile number an OTP will be sent and after verifying the OTP, I want to issue JWT for the user. Now, I have the below queries regarding this:

1. If this flow is correct or something needs to be changed?
2. Where should I store the OTP sent to the user's mobile number? Should I create a separate table for storing OTP and mobile numbers or it should be managed on the front-end site where I am using ReactJs?

Note: I cannot change the authentication mechanism from JWT to any other as I already have dependencies over it.

Comment: Hi @Sunny, if you are using Asp.net core Identity, you can store the phone number in the AspNetUsers table. To send the OTP verification in asp.net core, you could try to use [Multi-factor authentication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/mfa?view=aspnetcore-5.0) and [Enable QR Code generation for TOTP authenticator apps in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity-enable-qrcodes?view=aspnetcore-5.0).

Comment: No, I am not using Asp Net Core Identity. That's why I was thinking to create a separate table for that if my flow is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So when the user enters the mobile number an OTP will be sent and
> after verifying the OTP, I want to issue JWT for the user. Now, I have
> the below queries regarding this:
>
> 1. If this flow is correct or something needs to be changed?

First, I think the workflow is correct.

Generally, when we using JWT authentication, the workflow as below:

1. Client sends a request (which contains the user information, such as: name and password) to server for token
2. Server receives the user information and checking for authorization. If validated success, server generates a JWT token.
3. Client receives the token and stores it somewhere locally.
4. Client sends the token in the future requests.
5. Server gets the token from request header, computes Hash again by using a) Header from token b) payload from token c) secret key which server already has.
6. If ("newly computed hash" = "hash came in token"), token is valid otherwise it is tempered or not valid

So, in your workflow, you are using Mobile number and the OTP to login, and validate the user. It also is correct.

> 2. Where should I store the OTP sent to the user's mobile number? Should I create a
>    separate table for storing OTP and mobile numbers or it should be
>    managed on the front-end site where I am using ReactJs?

For this issue, I think it depends on how you generate/send the OTP.

If the OTP is generated by yourself, you have to store the phone number and OTP in the database, because, after client send the phone number and OTP to the server side, you have to validate whether the user is valid or not.

If you are using some provider or package to generate the OTP, might be the OTP has an expired time property, you can also store them in the database. If the expired time very short, there is no need to store them in database, you could try to use session to store the OTP.

Comment: can you suggest some provider or package to generate the OTP?

Comment: OtpNet nuget package supports TOTPs, you can use that.